# Using Ninject 3.0 for a given code

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

I'm trying to rewrite this code from DI autofac to Ninject 3.0.0.15.

I have problem with methods: [AsImplementedInterfaces(...)](http://api.autofac.org/html/AFD467AC.htm) and [AsClosedTypesOf(...)](http://api.autofac.org/html/3F8061C4.htm)

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CategoryRepository).Assembly)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .InstancePerHttpRequest();

Assembly services = Assembly.Load("EFMVC.Domain");

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services);
```

*The code is part of very nice demo web app for demonstrating ASP.NET MVC 4 and EF 4.3 Code First, Windows Azure and architectural practices: [EFMVC](http://efmvc.codeplex.com/)*

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Why would you want to change from Autofac to Ninject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ninject.Extensions.Conventions V3.0.0

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
      .FromAssemblyContaining<CategoryRepository>()
      .SelectAllClasses().EndingWith("Repository")
      .BindAllInterfaces()
      .Configure(b => b.InRequestScope());

kernel.Bind(x => x
      .From("EFMVC.Domain")
      .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFromAny(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
      .BindAllInterfaces()
      .Configure(b => b.InRequestScope());
```